# Why should type argument be specified when using method reference of a generic class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, method-reference, generic-type-argument

#### See [the YouTrack issue here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49150/Type-inference-fails-for-function-reference-and-generic-type).

Suppose I have a list of lists:

```
val wrapperList = listOf(
    listOf(1, 2),
    listOf(3, 4),
    listOf(5, 6)
)
```

Now this does NOT work in Kotlin:

```
wrapperList.groupBy(List::first, List::last)
```

Instead the type argument should be specified explicitly:

```
wrapperList.groupBy(List<Int>::first, List<Int>::last)
```

This is ugly.

Why is declaring the type mandatory?
Is it possible for Kotlin to infer it automatically like in its lambda expressions?